# How do I stop user input from printing a new line in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, user-input, mips32

I have an assignment for my college CS class that requires us to print out two triangles next to each other using user input. The user must enter an integer for the height of the triangles and a character that the triangles will be printed from.

I can take in the integer for the triangles' height fine, but printing the character the user inputs starts a new line every time instead of printing on the same line.

This is how I'm taking and printing the input:

```
    #Prompts user for character
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, charPrompt
    syscall

    #Stores character from user
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, userInput
    li $a1, 20
    move $t1, $a0
    syscall
    
    #Prints the character
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, userInput
    syscall
```

Here is my output. In order to figure out the shape of the triangles, I printed out `"*"` character under .data. All of the `"*"` are in the correct place, but the two `"e"` are are supposed to form the tops of those triangles. The ultimate goal is to print those exact triangles using whatever character the user inputs instead of `"*"`.

```
----e
-------------e

---*-*-----------***
--*---*---------*****
-*-----*-------*******
*********-----*********
```

I have it under .data as follows:

```
userInput: .space 1
```

Comment: Q: Have you considered building a *string* of characters, then printing the string (a line) at a time?  Instead of printing a character at a time?

Comment: That's not how the program is working. The triangles print one line at a time with me telling it where to print the character the user gave in order to form the triangles.

Answer (score 3):

When using syscall #8, MARS adds the user's newline character, which they used to terminate the input, to the resulting string that you receive from the syscall.

There are a number of options:

- Simply remove the newline from the syscall returned string
- Extract what you want from that input, like the first character, ignoring the rest of the string
- Use syscall #12 for input for character-by-syscall instead

---

Because syscall #8 does not return a length, then to remove the newline,  search for it, and replace it with a nul character.

Comment: Using syscall #12 didn't print the character at all. Do I need loops to extract the first character or remove the newline? Pretty new to MIPS so I'm not too sure how to go about it.

Comment: @user13508239: Not to extract the first character, you know where it will be (the first byte of the buffer you passed to the read system call).  But to replace the newline with a `0` byte to terminate the string early, yes you'd need a loop.  MARS's toy system calls suck and don't bother to return the number of characters read, only 0-terminating the string so you have to search for it, i.e. implement `strlen`.  (http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)

Comment: Syscall #12 inputs one character at a time, returned in $v0 (unlike syscall #8, it doesn't use a memory string buffer at all), so you need a loop to input more than one character, for example if you want to accept a newline to end the input or allow backspaces during input.  (Can't just change the syscall #.)

Comment: In your case, since you seem to only want one character, use syscall #8 and just use the first character, or convert the user input into a one character memory string by nul terminating it at index 1.